# Simple Ruby C extension cannot find ruby.h

Tags: c, ruby, extconf.rb, mkmf

I wrote an incredibly simple C extension for Ruby. Unfortunately, it can't find `ruby.h`.

Here is the `extconf.rb`:

```
require "mkmf"
$srcs = %w{hypergeometric.c}
$objs = %w{hypergeometric}
create_makefile("hypergeometric")
```

And here is the only source file:

```
#include <ruby.h> // have also tried #include "ruby.h", same error.
VALUE cHypergeometric;
void Init_hypergeometric() {
  cHypergeometric = rb_define_module("Hypergeometric");
}
```

When I try to compile this, I get the following error:

```
../../../../ext/hypergeometric/hypergeometric.c:1:18: error: ruby.h: No such file or directory
```

[Full gist.](https://gist.github.com/mohawkjohn/5834626#file-rake-compile-output) Note that line numbers are off because I've mostly commented out code instead of deleting it.

Interestingly, if I try to compile again without cleaning, I get a different error:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file hypergeometric, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0x67 0x70 0x63 0x68 0x43 0x30 0x31 0x33 0x38 0x4b 0x73 0x92 0x3d 0xf1 0xa5 0x62 ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): hypergeometric
```

(The full output is again included in the gist above.)

Perhaps this is a clue?

Why can't it find `ruby.h`? When I compile [NMatrix](http://github.com/SciRuby/nmatrix) or [the SciRuby rb-gsl fork](http://github.com/SciRuby/rb-gsl), both of these work fine and have no problem locating `ruby.h`. (For the record, I wrote NMatrix, C extension and all -- and I based this particular extension on that one's `extconf.rb`.)

Comment: Is ruby-dev package installed?

Comment: It's not Ubuntu, so no. Unless there's some way to install ruby-dev of which I am unaware on Mac OS X. But even if so, that wouldn't make sense since my other Ruby C extensions compile just fine.

Comment: looks like it is complaining about `ruby/subst.h` which it cannot `#include` from `ruby.h`.

Comment: Why is it looking in two locations for headers? I see `/System/Library/Frameworks/ruby.framework/Headers/intern.h:409` and `/Users/jwoods/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p195/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:1718`. Maybe not relevant, but seems strange to me.

Comment: you forgot object extension, should be: `$objs = %w{hypergeometric.o}`

Comment: @NARKOZ Thanks, only a year too late. =P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was astoundingly simple.

I had a line in my `extconf.rb`: `$objs = %w{hypergeometric}`, which I copied from a different project. It turns out I missed the second half of the line:

```
$objs = %w{hypergeometric}.map { |i| i + ".o" }
```

I cannot for the life of me understand why this change would allow it to suddenly find `ruby.h`.

In the end, the give-away was that weird error message:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file hypergeometric, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0x67 0x70 0x63 0x68 0x43 0x30 0x31 0x33 0x38 0x4b 0x73 0x92 0x3d 0xf1 0xa5 0x62 ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): hypergeometric
```

but odd that it only happens the *second* time I run `bundle exec rake compile`.